# Is it possible to define user permissions on a sheet basis in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, permissions

I have a Google spreadsheet with 10 sheets. Is it possible to define user permissions on a sheet basis in Google spreadsheet? For example, on sheet 1, user X can edit but user Y can only view.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, yeah that's what I feared :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `protect sheet` or `protect range` to define permission at the sheet or range level:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the two possible permission as of now are editing and commenting:

[image]